# Negative Acknowledgement to RabbitMQ Queue to Re-Queue the Message using Spring AMQP

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have an application which uses spring AMQP for consuming and producing messages to other application. 
I have a scenario where some of the exception occurred i need to re-queue back to RabbitMQ. For some exceptions i need to ignore (Basically i need to ignore the message no need to requeue)

Currently in below code, 
i have set the configuration as

**factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);**

But my requirement is to dynamically reject for some messages and re-queue back to RabbitMQ for some messages.

Please suggest

```
@Bean(name="rabbitListenerContainerFactory")
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
        Map<String, Class<?>> idClassMapping = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
        idClassMapping.put(Constants.JOB_TYPE_ID_, JobListenerDTO.class);
        classMapper.setIdClassMapping(idClassMapping);
        messageConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper);
        factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
        factory.setReceiveTimeout(10L);
        return factory;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it that way around (default false).

To do it selectively you have to set `defaultRequeueRejected` to `true` and throw `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueRejected` for any you want discarded.

You can encapsulate your desired logic in an `ErrorHandler`.

The default error handler does exactly that for a certain list of exceptions, as [documented here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#exception-handling) - you can inject a custom `FatalExceptionStrategy`.

But for conditional rejection, the `defaultRequeueRejected` must be `true`.

**EDIT**

```
factory.setErrorHandler(new ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler(t -> {
        Throwable cause = t.getCause();
        return cause instanceof MessageConversionException
                || cause instanceof org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException
                || cause instanceof MethodArgumentNotValidException
                || cause instanceof MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException
                || cause instanceof NoSuchMethodException
                || cause instanceof ClassCastException
                || cause instanceof MyBadXMLException;
    }));
```

This adds `MyBadXMLException` to the standard list.

If you are not using Java 8, use `new FatalExceptionStrategy() {...}`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Could you please provide me example which show case the use of ErrorHandler?

Comment: One more query, i have getting input as an xml from the producer. If the xml data is wrong, i am getting XML Exception. Only this exception i don't need to re-queue(How to do this ?). Rest all exceptions i need requeue. For that as you mention, i will set `defaultRequeueRejected ` to `true`

Comment: I read from rabbitmq link, `The AMQP specification defines the basic.reject method that allows clients to reject individual, delivered messages, instructing the broker to either discard them or requeue them.` Is it not supported in Spring AMQP ?

Comment: The container does that for you. Spring AMQP is an abstraction over ampq. If the listener exits normally, the container sends `basicAck`. If the listener throws an exception, it sends `basicReject`. Requeue or not depends on `defaultRequeueRejected` but that can be overridden (when true) by throwing an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`.

Comment: If you really want to take responsibility for acks in your listener, set the acknowledge mode to `MANUAL` and see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728668/spring-rabbitmq-using-manual-channel-acknowledgement-on-a-service-with-rabbit/38730821#38730821) for how to do it. But most people let the container do it.