# in Spring amqp how to encapsulate RabbitListener to a high level

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I use spring amqp in my project, and I use implements ChannelAwareMessageListener for re-send and handle exception to make rabbit listener more stable:

```
   public abstract class AbstractMessageListener implements ChannelAwareMessageListener {


    @Autowired
    private Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter;

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

    /** where comsumer really do biz */
    public abstract void receiveMessage(Message message, MessageConverter messageConverter);

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws Exception {
        MessageProperties messageProperties = message.getMessageProperties();
        Long deliveryTag = messageProperties.getDeliveryTag();
        Long consumerCount = redisTemplate.opsForHash().increment(MQConstants.MQ_CONSUMER_RETRY_COUNT_KEY,
                messageProperties.getMessageId(), 1);
        try {
            receiveMessage(message, messageConverter);
            channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);             
            redisTemplate.opsForHash().delete(MQConstants.MQ_CONSUMER_RETRY_COUNT_KEY,
                    messageProperties.getMessageId());
        } catch (Exception e) {

            if (consumerCount >= MQConstants.MAX_CONSUMER_COUNT) {               
                channel.basicReject(deliveryTag, false);
            } else {               
                Thread.sleep((long) (Math.pow(MQConstants.BASE_NUM, consumerCount)*1000));
                channel.basicNack(deliveryTag, false, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

then we can receive by extend our AbstractMessageListener like that:

```
public class BizMessageListener extends AbstractMessageListener  {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void receiveMessage(Message message, MessageConverter messageConverter) {
        //do our own biz
    }
}
```

but one day my boss said this way is too Invasion you mush use annotation instead， so I found something like that: [Spring RabbitMQ - using manual channel acknowledgement on a service with @RabbitListener configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728668/spring-rabbitmq-using-manual-channel-acknowledgement-on-a-service-with-rabbit)

where I can use annotation as

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "so38728668")
        public void receive(String payload, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag)
                throws IOException {
```

but how can I encapsulate @RabbitListener to a high level to combine my own re-send msg code in my first code sample , for example there is a annotation as RabbitResenderListener

```
 @RabbitResenderListener(queues = "so38728668")
            public void receive(Message msg)
                    throws IOException {
 // just do biz 
}
```

this annotation give the method re-send msg and error-handle ability, so that the method only do biz. thks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you expect from us, but seems for me annotations are not for extensions and extracting abstractions like we can do with classes.

Anyway I can share some idea you may try.

There is a method level `@RabbitHandler` annotation. So, you can mark a method in super class with that and do all the infrastructure logic. The target implementation should be marked with the particular `@RabbitListener` on the class to bring the required `queues` configuration. The `@RabbitHandler` method will call the polymorphic method from the inheritor.

Does it sound reasonable?

Comment: Yeah, that what I want to do, instead I do not want to make a super class, because if I make a super class, ever listener we will write must extend this super class, as it's called intrusive. What I want to do is to  write a class extend some amqp source code, and write my infrastructure logic in this class. then ever class with @RabbitListener can only do business logic which means non-intrusive.

Comment: Would be great to see some PoC, but anyway the `@RabbitListener` is already AMQP source and it is very tied to the method contract and it is very close to the listener container. You might need to take a look into Spring Integration for the next level of abstraction between services: https://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/

Comment: Hi, I found class MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java in amqp source code, I think maybe I can override onMessage() method and add my own infrastructure logic. whether this work? And how to do that, can spring recognize my new class by extend MessagingMessageListenerAdapter ? or  there are other methods  to overlap source code of amqp? thx

Comment: No, you can't do that. That's very specific code and tied with the whole annotation processing. You may consider to implement some AOP Advice though, which can be applied to selected business services and may call an appropriate infrastructure logic. The `@RabbitListener` has `containerFactory()` option, where that `AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactory` can be supplied with the `adviceChain`.