# How to acknowledge all successful messages with "Mono" handler?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, project-reactor, spring-amqp

I'm working with [spring amqp](https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp) and I use asynchronous return types like `Mono`. The one of my handlers:

```java
    @RabbitHandler
    public Mono<Response<PopularityReport>> popularityReport(PopularityReportCommand command) {
        return Mono.just(foo);
    }
```

When I use such an approach I get the next warning:

```
[ntContainer#0-1] .a.r.l.a.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Container AcknowledgeMode must be MANUAL for a Mono<?> return type; otherwise the container will ack the message immediately
```

I could use the next [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728668/spring-rabbitmq-using-manual-channel-acknowledgement-on-a-service-with-rabbit/38730821) for manual acknowledgments. But I have a hundred handlers and for this reason, that approach seems me like inconvenient (I need to change all handlers).

I wanna acknowledge all messages only after successful execution.
How could I write a global strategy for all my handlers in one place without changing the old code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually ack such messages; the framework takes care of it when the `Mono` completes.

The warning is just to tell you that the container is not configured properly for this return type.

Comment: yes, it seems so. Can you please tell me where I can see it (in the code)?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/bd088731b08ceb7ca90543e18b19cbf70a21c6c8/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/adapter/AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java#L396-L399