# RabbitMQ BasicAck giving channel shutdown error messages on console - Spring AMQP

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

```
@EnableRabbit
@Service
public class RabbitMqListenerWithReply {


@Autowired
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@Value("${test.rabbitmq.exchange}")
private String rabbitMQExchange;


@Value("${test.rabbitmq.routingkey}")
private String rabbitMQRoutingKey;

@RabbitListener(queues = "${test.rabbitmq.queue}")
public void receiveMessage(String message, Channel channel, 
@Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG)long tag) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(message.toString());
    channel.basicAck(tag, false);
    System.out.println("Ackd"); 
    
}
}
```

I am trying to implement a listener which acknowledge the message after I consume it, however the console would return this error so can someone guide me on where I could have went wrong.

This is the error that I am getting right now whenever I run the publisher to publish the message to the exchange.

```
2022-01-03 09:35:33.192 ERROR 27280 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1, class-id=60, method-id=80)

2022-01-03 09:35:34.208  INFO 27280 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@52d7ab79: tags=[[amq.ctag-0pIM_-TROTIxXRsAJpmOrw]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@71369e1a Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@60b616c8 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 57660], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
```

This is how I am publishing my message at the moment.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/test")
public class RestAPIController {
@Autowired
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@Value("${test.rabbitmq.exchange}")
private String rabbitMQExchange;

@Value("${test.rabbitmq.routingkey}")
private String rabbitMQRoutingKey;

@Value("${test.rabbitmq.queue}")
private String rabbitMQQueue;



@GetMapping("{message}")
public String testAPI(@PathVariable("message") String message) {
    System.out.println("Message sent: " + message);
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(rabbitMQExchange, rabbitMQRoutingKey , message);
    return "The message was sent";
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@RabbitListener` use [AUTO-ACK](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#containerAttributes) by default.

> The container acknowledges the message automatically, unless the MessageListener throws an exception.

So if you ack once in  `listener`, the framework will ack once, and repeating ack causes this exception.

Try:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "xxx", ackMode = "MANUAL")
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications on the error, sorry if I may clarify further.
Would I be required to use :
channel.basicConsume to properly acknowledge the message after using channel.basicAck

Comment: The listener container is already a consumer.  You can not use ```basicConsume``` in the listener. You can take a look at this quesition: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38775174/9690075)

Comment: Hi Zysaaa, I kinda understand what you meant when you mention that the container is already a consumer. I have visited the link which you posted, in my case am I using my channel.basicAck wrongly to acknowledge the messages?

Comment: If you set ackMode = "AUTO"(which is by default), you don't have to call```channel.basicAck``` in your listener method.  If you want to manually ack or uack message, then the current approach is correct, you only need to set the ackMode = MANUAL of the current listener to avoid double ack.

Comment: I see, in that case how can I verify that my message has already been manually acknowledged using my code snippets?

Thanks in advance for the advise Zysaaa, if you happened to have any Rabbitmq Tutorial I would gladly be happy to join it to enhance my knowledge of it.

Comment: What do you mean by ```message has already been manually acknowledged```. I think official [Tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) and [Spring-Amqp-Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#introduction) is a good start

Comment: Thanks Zysaaa for the pointers I have figured out the reason of not using a consumer inside a consumer. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Please consider [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it helped you!

Comment: Opps totally forget about checking the tick right beside!